# Counterexamples to Kollár's conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, counterexamples

In "[Singularities of theta divisors, and birational geometry
of irregular varieties](http://www.ams.org/jams/1997-10-01/S0894-0347-97-00223-3/)", Jour. AMS 10, 1 (1997), 243–258, L. Ein and R. Lazarsfeld provided a counterexample to Kollár's conjecture, i.e. an irregular 3-fold of general type of maximal Albanese dimension with Euler characteristic = 0. Their example can be trivially generalized to higher dimension.

My question is: are other counterexamples to Kollár's conjecture known? Where can I find them?

Thank you very much for the time dedicated to me
Best regards

Answer (score 6):

I just saw this question (better late than never). The following references come to mind (the first one has an example which somewhat improves on the example of Ein-Lazarsfeld, the others have a variety of related results):

The Example at the end of Chen and Hacon "[On the irregularity of the image of the Iitaka fibration](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~jkchen/finalversion/iitaka.pdf). Comm. in Algebra Vol. 32, No. 1, pp. 203-215 (2004), doi: [10.1081/AGB-120027861](http://dx.doi.org/10.1081/AGB-120027861) .

Example 5.6 in [arXiv:1111.6279](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6279) On the Iitaka fibration of varieties of maximal Albanese dimension. Zhi Jiang, Martí Lahoz, Sofia Tirabassi.

[arXiv:1105.3418](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3418) Varieties with vanishing holomorphic Euler characteristic. J. A. Chen, O. Debarre, Z. Jiang.

Cai, Jin-Xing; Chen, Jungkai Alfred: A note on characterizations of Abelian varieties by topological invariants. Manuscripta Math. 112 (2003), no. 1, 15–19, doi: [10.1007/s00229-003-0384-2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00229-003-0384-2).